# Python count multiple values in dictionary of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

I have been trying to count the values in a dictionary with respect to the key. However, I could not achieved desired result. I will demonstrate with more details below:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'a': ['Adam','Adam','John'], 'b': ['John','John','Joel'], 'c': ['Adam','Adam','John}
# create a list of only the values you want to count,
# and pass to Counter()
c = Counter([values[1] for values in d.itervalues()])
print c
```

My output:

```
Counter({'Adam': 2, 'John': 1})
```

I want it to count everything in the list, not just first value of the list. Also, I want my result to be with respect to the key. I will show you my desired output below:

```
{'a': [{'Adam': 1, 'John': 2}, 'b':{'John': 2, 'Joel': 1}, 'c':{'Adam': 2, 'John': 1 }]}
```

Is it possible to get this desired output? Or anything close to it? I would like to welcome any suggestions or ideas that you have. Thank you.

Comment: this has been asked a lot of times.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I have tried to search online for a solution for hours. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it. Could it give me link to it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `dict comprehension`

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'a': ['Adam','Adam','John'], 'b': ['John','John','Joel'], 'c': ['Adam','Adam','John'}
c = {i:Counter(j) for i,j in d.items()}
print c
```

Comment: Hi, do you elaborate further? Sorry. I am still new to python. Thank you!

Comment: Is it you desired solution? Look at `python dict comprehension` and https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter. Its simple

Comment: Sorry. I could find information related to dict comprehension based on the link given by you. Did u give me a wrong link?

Comment: link that was about `Counter`. About `dict comprehension` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: I have read about it. This is what I want. But I have no idea how how should i go about doing it? Pardon me. Do you have idea about it? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. It works like wonder. Thank you. I am a little confused how does dict comprehension works? How does --> `c = {i:Counter(j) for i,j in d.items()}` works?  Also, is there a way to remove the word "Counter" from the output? Thank you so much.

Comment: its looping over `d.items()` and creating `key:value`.  if you want to remove `Counter` ==> `c = {i:dict(Counter(j)) for i,j in d.items()}`

Answer (score 1):

You're picking only the first elements in the each list with `values[1]`, instead, you want to iterate through each values using a `for` that follows the first:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> d = {'a': ['Adam','Adam','John'], 'b': ['John','John','Joel'], 'c': ['Adam','Adam','John']}
>>> Counter([v for values in d.itervalues() for v in values]) # iterate through each value
Counter({'John': 4, 'Adam': 4, 'Joel': 1})
```

Comment: Hi your solution is great. However, is it possible to the outside to produce the result that is linked to the dictionary? For eg `{'a': [{'Adam': 1, 'John': 2}` Thanks!